# C# deserialization type downcasting with xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, mono, xml-serialization

[Execution Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMy9W.png)

Once the object is deserialized C# prints the correct object type but doesn't allow me to downcast it. Can anybody explain why?

The project involves two programs (Server and client) trying to serialize c# objects over a TCP connection.

The code is running on linux under mono 4.5 and it is intended to be running a Unity script.

I have also tried the Binary Formatter with exacly the same result

I quote here code on both ends:

> 

```
        private void   listenerMethod ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Listening to packets");
            try {
                while (true){
                    System.Object o = this.xmlSerializerIn.Deserialize(this.stream);
                    Console.WriteLine("Object string: "+o.ToString());
                    try{
                        Game.Message.DebugMsgGame debug= (Game.Message.DebugMsgGame) o;
                        Console.WriteLine(debug);
                    }catch (InvalidCastException e){
                        Console.WriteLine (e);
                        Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
                    }
                    try{
                        Game.Message.IGameMessage gm= (Game.Message.IGameMessage) o;
                        gm.Process(this.gl,((IPEndPoint)this.tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address);
                    }catch (InvalidCastException e){
                        Console.WriteLine (e);
                        Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
                    }
                }
            } catch (ArgumentNullException e) {
                Console.WriteLine (e);
            } catch (SerializationException e) {
                Console.WriteLine (e);
            }
        }
>  
 On the server side
> 
        public void Send (Game.Message.IGameMessage gm)
        {
            this.xmlSerializerOut.Serialize (stream, gm);
        }
>
The message object
>

namespace Game.Message
{
    [Serializable]
        public class DebugMsgGame: IGameMessage {
          private string debugString;

            public DebugMsgGame(string str){
                this.debugString=str;
            }

            public void Process(Server.IGameListener gl, System.Net.IPAddress ip)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.debugString);
                gl.Debug("Someting intelligent");
            }

            new public string ToString(){
              return this.debugString;
            }
        }
}

>
```

Comment: How is `xmlSerializerIn` constructed?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here. I can only guess that the class and interface are defined more than once.

Comment: The interface in is built as follows:    this.xmlSerializerIn = new XmlSerializer (typeof(Game.Message.DebugMsgGame));  There is no other interface or class named as that one in the whole program, let alone on that same namespace.

Comment: @CharlesMager, could you be more specific?, I've tried to comply to those standards. First question on StackOverflow